# Not getting response in Laravel from FollowButton.vue file

Tags: php, laravel, controller, httpresponse

Below is the script for getting response(FollowButton.vue)
Note: `followUser()` method is invoked on Follow button click

```
<script>

    export default {
        props:['userId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        },

        methods:{
            followUser(){
                axios.post('/follow/'+this.userId)
                    .then(response => {
                       alert(response.data);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Below file snippet is for routing (web.php)

```
Route::post('follow/{user}','FollowsController@store');
```

Below file is Controller file (FollowController.php);

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FollowsController extends Controller
{
    public function store(User $user)
    {
        return $user->username;
    }
}
```

[I am getting the following errors after i click 'Follow' button(In console)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUlkV.png)

[Error in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrTmC.png)

Comment: have you send the csrf token?

Comment: Please look into storage/log/larave.log file to complete stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Does `$user->username` exist? By default it's `$user->name`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue..it was in FollowController.php
I show the following message in network tab on browser:
   Class App\Http\Controllers\User does not exist

So,instead of (User $user) i have to write (\App\User $user)...